# html/php search text inside multible PDF files

Tags: php, html, cakephp, pdf

I have several pdf files on my site, what I want is to have a code html, php or any other language to allow the visitor to write a word and my site search inside the PDF files, then get the result as clickable title of the pdf file and phrase of text found, when the title clicked then the browser will open this pdf.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to roll your own:

1. Change the PDF files into something that you can search.

   Using XPDF: http://www.foolabs.com/xpdf/about.html

   ```
   $content = shell_exec('/usr/local/bin/pdftotext '.$filename.' -'); //dash at the end to output content
   ```

   Also. http://coolwanglu.github.com/pdf2htmlEX/
2. Use Google Custom Search or your own search script to just search the HTML pages that you created in step 1.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you want a PHP spider: http://www.sphider.eu/

Also, Google Custom Search should also be able to index pdfs.